# Storing some data with nodejs?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm writing a lastfm plugin for a chat bot my friend wrote, and one of the things I'd like to is allow people to register their hostmask/nick with their lastfm username (something like !reg lastfmuser would store that username with the hostmask/nick for whoever said it). The framework and plugins are written in  javascript/nodejs. I'm not sure where to start at all on storing/accessing this data on the disk or however it would be done.

Basically, I want to have a file that it can look through when someone calls a lastfm command (nowplaying, compare, topartists) and it'll use the stored username instead of their nick if possible. So the file would be something like:

```
Hostname | Nick | Lastfmuser
```

I've never written something that stores data on the disk, or has to read from the disk, and I'm still fairly new to nodejs/javascript. I looked at alfred.js, but ended up confused and not sure if that's what I really wanted.

Comment: You should use a database. MongoDB, for example.

Comment: Sounds like a job for a simple database.  Maybe a noSQL DB like MongoDB...?  Yeah, what @Sergio said.  :)

Comment: I'll look into it, I've never put together/maintained a db on my own. Sounds like fun, though. Previous similar plugin used bdb, maybe there's a node package for berkeley db already.

Comment: mongoDB seems to be the way to go for this, and will let me do some more cool things I'd like to do.

Comment: Is this a command line utility program written in Node.js, or are we talking about a web service written in Node.js. If the latter then @Sergio is right that you probably want a database for performance purposes. If the former, then all you need is [the built-in 'fs' module](http://nodejs.org/api/fs.html). For simplicity, fs.readFile and fs.writeFile will let you read a file in as a big string, and then write a string out to disk. Performance for many users would be bad, but for a single user, just put it in something like "~/.chatbot-lastfm"

Comment: It's for a fairly large irc channel, so I'm probably going to go with mongoDB or similar. If @SergioTulentsev makes it an answer, I'll accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you insist :)

When a person wants to store some data to be read/manipulated later, he should use database in most cases. There are cases when files are more preferable, but this is not one of them.

Schemaless database (like MongoDB) is a good fit here, because it allows faster prototyping and development (as opposed to relational databases with fixed schema).

Comment: I actually went with mongoDB, node module mongoose, and it's up and running great. You can check it out at https://github.com/theVDude/ircnode_plugins/blob/05c37b3518fdb31b9d94ac652f4f9dda463dde11/lastfm.js